# qTime, checking value of timer?

Tags: qt

I have a timer and when the time is equal to a certain time, ie. 5 seconds, 10 second, 12 seconds. I want it to do something.

What is the best way of constantly checking the timers value to see if it matches my value?

Comment: I think you need 1 timer for 5 sec, 1 timer for 10 sec, 1 timer for 12 second interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling the time of a QTime is a bad idea. You have QTimer for that, which uses the hardware timer facilities of your platform. Set up a single-shot QTimer to 5 seconds. Connect its timeout() signal to a slot, and in that slot reprogram the QTimer for your next interval. The general concept of that is:

```
int intervals[] = {5000, 10000, 12000};
// Alternative:
// int intervals[] = {5000, 5000, 2000};
int currentInterval = 0;
QTimer timer; // Make sure you set this up a single-shot timer.

// ...

// slot
void handleTimeout()
{
    ++currentInterval;
    // You should probably use a QList<int> instead in your real code and query size().
    if (currentInterval >= sizeof(intervals) / sizeof(intervals[0])) {
        // We're done.
        return;
    }
    timer.start(intervals[currentInterval] - intervals[currentInterval - 1]);
    // Alternative:
    // timer.start(intervals[currentInterval]);
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a call to `timer.start()` in the handleTimeout function.

Comment: Remember that by default QTimers aren't very precise. With long lists of intervals, this solution will drift further and further away from the actual time. It may be better to use a QTime in conjunction with a QTimer. Instead of using the "current interval" to determine the current time, use the QTime object for a more precise reading.